# C# linq remove duplicates from the top and bottom of the list and keep the duplicates in the middle

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

C# linq remove duplicates from the *top* and *bottom* of the list and keep the duplicates in the *middle*

**For example,**

```
  var myArray = new[] { 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9 
  };
  
  List<int> myList = myArray.ToList();
```

**Expected Output** after removing the duplicates at the top and bottom is below list

```
{ 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 };
```

Please advice how to perform this logic and tried `myList.Distinct()` wouldn't help as it remove *all* the duplicates in the middle as well.

**EDIT: The list will not be EMPTY and regardless of the duplicate at the top and bottom, the first and last records should be removed for calculation of a business logic. If duplicates are found at the top or bottom, should be removed as well. The list will be ordered ascending before performing the removal operation **

Comment: If you have one or more 1's or 9's in the middle, do you want to keep or remove them? Also, what if the first/last element is _not_ a duplicate; would you like to keep or remove that?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Updated the question

Comment: This is a specification, not a question. Where do you experience a problem programming this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myList = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9 };
    var topDublicate = myList.First();
    var lastDublicate = myList.Last();

    myList.RemoveAll(l => l == topDublicate);
    myList.RemoveAll(l => l == lastDublicate);
```

Comment: 1. Your code throws exception on *empty list*. 2. Your code removes the first an the last items even when they are not duplicated, e.g. `{1, 2, 3}`: actual `{2}` when `{1, 2, 3}` expected.

Answer (score 2):

For removing the duplicates in the beginning of the list, you could benefit from `.First()` and `.SkipWhile()` in the *System.Linq* namespace:

```csharp
var firstDuplicate = myList.First();

var listWithoutFirstDuplicate = myList
    .SkipWhile(l => l == firstDuplicate)
    .ToList();
```

For removing the duplicates in the *end* of the list, you would benefit from `.Last()` and `.SkipLastWhile()`, *had `.SkipLastWhile()` existed*:

```csharp
var lastDuplicate = myList.Last();

var listWithoutLastDuplicate = myList
    .SkipLastWhile(l => l == lastDuplicate)
    .ToList();
```

Paulo Morgado has suggested an implementation of `.SkipLastWhile()` in [this blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/paulomorgado/linq-implementing-the-skiplastwhile-operator). It looks like this:

```csharp
public static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipLastWhile<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    var buffer = new List<TSource>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            buffer.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            if (buffer.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var bufferedItem in buffer)
                {
                    yield return bufferedItem;
                }

                buffer.Clear();
            }

            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Paulo's implementation of `.SkipLastWhile()` checks each element against the predicate. If the predicate is *not* fulfilled for an element, the element is returned. If the predicate *is* fulfilled (i.e. in your scenario: if the element is equal to `lastDuplicate`), the element is not immediately returned, but rather added to a buffer. The contents of the buffer is only returned if a succeeding element does *not* fulfill the predicate.

---

A few examples:

```
{ 1, 9, 9, 9, 9 }.SkipLastWhile(i => i == 9)
```

will return `{ 1 }`.
The buffer will build up from `{ 9 }` (the element at index 1) to `{ 9, 9, 9, 9 }` (the elements from index 1 to index 4), and will *not* be returned.

```
{ 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1 }.SkipLastWhile(i => i == 1)
```

will return `{ 1, 9, 9, 9, 9 }`.
The buffer will first be `{ 1 }` (the element at index 0), then be returned and emptied when `9` is found (at index 1). When reaching the last element, the buffer will again be  be `{ 1 }`; and it is not returned.

```
{ 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9 }.SkipLastWhile(i => i == 9)
```

will return `{ 9, 1 }`.
The buffer will first be `{ 9 }` (the element at index 0), then be returned and emptied when `1` is found (at index 1). When reaching `9` (at index 2), the buffer starts building up again, starting with `{ 9 }`. At the last element, the buffer will be `{ 9, 9, 9, 9 }`, and its contents are *not* returned.

---

Using this implementation of `SkipLastWhile()`, you can get your filtered list:

```csharp
var myList = new List<int> { 1, 1, 9, 2, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5, 5, 1, 9, 9 };

var firstDuplicate = myList.First();
var lastDuplicate = myList.Last();

var myFilteredList = myList
    .SkipWhile(l => l == firstDuplicate)
    .SkipLastWhile(l => l == lastDuplicate)
    .ToList();
```

The output for the given `myList` is the following:

> 9, 2, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5, 5, 1

---

As pointed out by [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko), there are two problems with this implementation:

1. If `myList` is `null` or empty (`{ }`), and exception is thrown

   - none of the extension methods can tolerate being called on `null`
   - `.First()` (and `.Last()`) throw an exception when being called on an empty list
2. If the first element is no duplicate (i.e. not equal to the second element), the first element will nonetheless be excluded; that is not expected behavior. Similarily, the last element will also be excluded, even if it is no duplicate.

One way to address these problems is to make checks along the way before filtering out actual duplicates. If handled in a method, it could be implemented like this:

```csharp
public static List<int> GetFilteredList(List<int> list)
{
    // if list is null; return null
    if (list == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    // If list is empty or contains only one element; return list as new list
    if (!list.Skip(1).Any())
    {
        return list.ToList();
    }
    
    var filtered = list.AsEnumerable();
    
    // Remove duplicates at beginning of list (if any)
    if (list.First() == list.Skip(1).First())
    {
        filtered = filtered.SkipWhile(l => l == list.First());
    }
    
    // Remove duplicates at end of list (if any)
    if (list.Last() == list.SkipLast(1).Last())
    {
        filtered = filtered.SkipLastWhile(l => l == list.Last());
    }
    
    return filtered.ToList();
}
```

It may be called as follows:

```
var filteredList = GetFilteredList(myList);
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KoLrXP).

Comment: Your last code *throws exception* on *empty list* (`var myList = new List<int> {};`) and cut off the first and the last items even when they are *not duplicates*:  `(`var myList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`, here I expected `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` but got `2, 3, 4`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You're absolutely right; thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Updated (addressing the issues and adding a suggested implementation for how to handle them).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove duplicates just from the very top and bottom of the collection, but want to keep the *same* values int the middle:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 8, 8, 9, 9, 4, 5, 9, 9 => 2, 3, 1, 1, 8, 8, 9, 9, 4, 5
                                                  ^  ^     ^  ^
                                                    preserved
```

you can compute `left` and `right` borders and then trim the collection with a help of `Skip` and `Take`:

```
      int[] myArray = new int[] { 
        ... 
      };

      ...

      int left = 0;

      for (int i = 1; i < myArray.Length; ++i)
        if (myArray[i - 1] == myArray[i])
          left = i + 1;
        else
          break;

      int right = myArray.Length - 1;

      for (int i = myArray.Length - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        if (myArray[i + 1] == myArray[i])
          right = i - 1;
        else
          break;

      List<int> myList = myArray
        .Skip(left)
        .Take(right - left + 1)
        .ToList();
```

If you want to remove all the values which are appeared to be duplicates

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 8, 8, 9, 9, 4, 5, 9, 9 => 2, 3, 8, 8, 4, 5
```

you can collect these values and then filter out:

```
      int[] myArray = new int[] { 
        ... 
      };

      ...

      HashSet<int> remove = new HashSet<int>();

      if (myArray.Length > 1) {
        if (myArray[0] == myArray[1])
          remove.Add(myArray[0]);
        if (myArray[myArray.Length - 1] == myArray[myArray.Length - 2])
          remove.Add(myArray[myArray.Length - 1]);
      }

      var myList = myArray
        .Where(item => !remove.Contains(item))
        .ToList();
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u6OFlB)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int topDuplicate = myList [0];
    myList .RemoveAll(x => x == topDuplicate);
    int bottomDuplicate = myList [myList .Count - 1];
    myList .RemoveAll(x => x == bottomDuplicate);
```

Comment: 1. Your code throws exception on *empty list*. 2. Your code removes the first an the last items even when they are not duplicated, e.g. `{1, 2, 3}`: actual `{2}` when `{1, 2, 3}` expected.